# How to skip cucmber steps if certain condition matched

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-java

In cucumber with java i am writing a test case, where in one step i am looking for one web element.
If this web element is not found then i want to skip all the steps below this and also wants to mark this scenario as pass.

How to do that ?

When User logs into application
Then check if element is present (if this web element is not present then skip below steps)
Then navigate to Queue page
Then click on Fetch button

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can rewrite the Gherkin Steps in a way that is not conditional. And within the step that is where you can write the condition as an if-else statement.

```
Scenario: --
  Given --
  When User logs into application
  Then navigate to fetch button

--

@Then('navigate to fetch button')
  // check the element
  // add an if-else statement
```